# Rewrite nonlinear equation system

Tags: nonlinear-system

Is there anyway to rewrite this system to a system of $Q_1$,$Q_2$,$Q_3$ and $Q_4$ instead? $a,b,c,d,m$ are real numbers.

$$\begin{align}
    a&=Q_1^2-Q_2^2-Q_3^2+Q_4^2+m\\
    b&=2Q_1Q_2-2Q_3Q_4\\
    c&=2Q_1Q_3+2Q_2Q_4\\
    d&=Q_1^2+Q_2^2+Q_3^2+Q_4^2\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Please use MathJax notation in order to make this question readable

Comment: You want to solve this system for $$Q_1,Q_2,Q_3,Q_4$$?